# Cannot Access Website via IP

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

I have hosted my website as an application on IIS and I can access it by `http:\localhost\myApp\default.aspx` but not with my IP.

I have another application hosted in the same machine which can be accessible in both `localhost` and `IP address`.

**Error message from different browsers:**

```
IE: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Firefox: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.**

Chrome: This webpage is not available
```

I can access all other pages except `default.aspx`.

**What `default.aspx` does?**

> It just loads a flash file.

**What happens when I browse `http:\localhost\myApp\default.aspx`?**

> It redirects to `https:\localhost\myApp\default.aspx`

Note the `s` above.

**Few other detais:**

- `Port 80` is enabled.
- Read permission is there for `default.aspx`.
- The website is hosted as application under `Default Web Site` and the `http` binding is `All Unassigned`.
- Created a separate pool with `Integrated` pipeline mode.

**What might be the cause for this issue?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a strange code inside the `default.aspx` page, which was redirecting the page to `https` if the server is not `localhost` along with some other condition, there by causing the server to refuse the request.

Sorry for the stupidity, I could have check that before asking a question here.

Comment: Just remember to give your answer the checkbox once enough time has passed :)

Answer (score 3):

Check that your webserver is configured to listen on your 192.168.** IP address. Check that your firewall has port 80 on your 192.168.** IP address open.

Comment: The port `80` is enabled for the IP. The strange thing I noticed is, I'm able to access the pages other than the `default.aspx`. I'm getting the above error only for that page(default.aspx). Please let me know, for any further clarifications.

Comment: Check that the webserver has permission to read the default.aspx file.

Comment: Yes the permission is there. Well, the other thing I noticed is, when I browse `http:\localhost\myApp\default.aspx` it is automatically redirecting to `https`.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds most likely to be a firewall issue, if port 80 is closed to the outside world it would still be available on the loopback address (localhost).

What version of Windows are you running? The more info we have the more we can help you reconfigure your firewall. Alternatively you could just momentarily disable the firewall to perform the test and go from there.

Also, is your other application hosted on the standard webserver port in IIS? If so then the above probably won't help, one other thing to check is the bindings for the website - open iis, then drill down to the individual site in the connections bar on the left, then take a look on the right and click bindings. If the bindings are set to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 then that will be your issue, you either have to assign it to "All unassigned" or an individual IP.

It also might be that you've assigned an IP to your other project and therefore the "all unassigned" option only gives you the loopback address as an option, if in the drop down box the only option is "All unassigned" then this is probably the case. The fix, in this case, would be to set your other project to be "All unassigned" too.

Comment: Please check my comments on lain's post.

Comment: The binding is `All unassigned`.